# How to transform array to XML objects in DataWeave 1.0?

Tags: dataweave

How can I transform the following object to XML?

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml encoding="UTF-8", skipNullOn="everywhere"
%namespace soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
---
soap#Body: {
  Array: [
    {
      Item:"test 1"
    },
    {
      Item:"test 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected output would be same as DataWeave 2.0

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Array>
    <Item>test 1</Item>
  </Array>
  <Array>
    <Item>test 2</Item>
  </Array>
</soap:Body>
```

But currently I get an error instead

```
Message               : Exception while executing: 
  Array: [
         ^
Cannot coerce a :array to a :object.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because DataWeave can convert Objects into XML elements, however there is no array concept in XML, so it fails. Instead you need to transform the array into an object. I used the reduce() function by concatenating each item object. Note that you are using Array incorrectly, because you want to enclose each item into a separate Array element.

```js
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml encoding="UTF-8", skipNullOn="everywhere"
%namespace soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
---
{
  soap#Body: 
  [
    {
      Item:"test 1"
    },
    {
      Item:"test 2"
    }
  ] reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ { Array: item})
}
```